# How to Access Exception Class Variables?

Tags: java, exception

I am implementing custom Exception for Employee Service class. now want getter function for Exception class variables.

```
package com.sentienz.service.exception;

public class EmployeeServiceCustomException extends Exception {

    private final int code;
    private final String genericmessage;

    public EmployeeServiceCustomException(int code, String genericmessage) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.genericmessage = genericmessage;
    }

    public EmployeeServiceCustomException(String message, Throwable cause, int code, String genericmessage) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.code = code;
        this.genericmessage = genericmessage;
    }

    public EmployeeServiceCustomException(String message, int code, String genericmessage) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
        this.genericmessage = genericmessage;
    }

    public EmployeeServiceCustomException(Throwable cause, int code, String genericmessage) {
        super(cause);
        this.code = code;
        this.genericmessage = genericmessage;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public String getGenericmessage() {
        return this.genericmessage;
    }



}
```

Actually, I want this but I am not able to do this. is java exception class has all private variable or some other other reason for this problem.

```
 public int getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that `Throwable` already declares `getMessage()` with return type `String`. `int` is not return type compatible with `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to write your own `getMessage` since there is already one in the parent class [`Throwable.getMessage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage()) - which you simply inherit anyway.